# How to create an object if one of it's properties requires a value of a promise

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous, promise, response

How can i use the value of a promise to add it to an object property? If anyone can help me ill appreciate it.

//dolar.js

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const url ='https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json';

async function getTasaDolar(priceBs) {
  axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
    return response.data.USD.transferencia;
  }).catch(function(error) {
  }).then(function(response) {{
    console.log('--------');
    console.log(priceBs/response);
    return priceBs/response;
  }});
}

module.exports = getTasaDolar;
```

//object.js

```
const getTasaDolar = require('./dolar.js');

async function myFunc ({name, brand, category, priceBs}) {
    const object =  {
        name,
        brand,
        category,
        priceBs,
        priceDolar :  getTasaDolar(priceBs)
    }

    return object;
}

const hola =  myFunc({name:`hola`, brand: `Chocozuela`, category:`Carnes`, priceBs:645000});
console.log(hola);
```

When I run this the output is :

```
Promise {
  { name: 'hola',
    brand: 'Chocozuela',
    category: 'Carnes',
    priceBs: 645000,
    priceDolar: Promise { undefined } } }
--------
3.467229680260142.
```

As you can see the value 3.46 is consoled.log but when i console.log the hola object the property priceDolar is Promise {undefined}

Comment: `getTasaDolar` function doesn't return anything - try `return axios.get(url)........` - and since it's an async function, its definitely going to return a promise ... so you'll need to `await getTasaDolar`

Comment: why are you using two then blocks?

Comment: `getTasaDolar` is also `async` for no reason

Comment: I tried to format your code so it was a little more readable but what's up with those double-braces, ie `.then(function(response) {{` 

Comment: @Phil - it's valid code :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declaring a function as `async` is not enough; you still have to `await` the Promises before you can use their results.

First problem is that `getTasaDolar` is not awaiting anything. To fix:

```
async function getTasaDolar(priceBs) {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  return priceBs / response.data.USD.transferencia;
}
```

Now you also have to await this in `myFunc`:

```
async function myFunc ({name, brand, category, priceBs}) {
  return {
    name,
    brand,
    category,
    priceBs,
    priceDolar: await getTasaDolar(priceBs)
  };
}
```

And yes, asynchronicity has bubbled up to `myFunc` as well, so if you want to call that you have to use `await` *or* a Promise callback:

```
myFunc({name:`hola`, brand: `Chocozuela`, category:`Carnes`, priceBs:645000})
  .then(hola => console.log(hola));
```

Perhaps you had what seems to be a common misconception that making a function `async` tells JavaScript to automatically wait for async things, but all it *really* means is you can use the keyword `await`, which is a more convenient way to call the `.then(...)`, `.catch(...)` and `.finally(...)` Promise methods.

Comment: I can almost see the followup problem, that `myFunc` is returning a promise :p

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here:
1) `getTasaDolar` returns `undefined` because it doesn't explicitly return anything
2) You do not wait for the Promise to resolve when calling `getTasaDolar`

The `getTasaDolar` doesn't need to be `async` because it doesn't use `await`. Also there's no need for a `catch` since whoever is calling it can handle that. You were consuming the error which would cause the response to be undefined. Here's how I'd adjust this function:

```
function getTasaDolar(priceBs) {
  return axios
    .get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      const data = response.data.USD.transferencia;
      console.log("--------");
      console.log(priceBs / data);
      return priceBs / data;
    });
}
```

The `myFunc` function is good to be `async` and you should `await` the result of the first function. But where you call `myFunc` has to use `.then` to see the returned value because `myFunc` is `async` and therefore returns a `Promise` object.

```
async function myFunc({ name, brand, category, priceBs }) {
  const object = {
    name,
    brand,
    category,
    priceBs,
    priceDolar: await getTasaDolar(priceBs) // <-- await here
  };

  return object;
}

myFunc({name:`hola`, brand: `Chocozuela`, category:`Carnes`, 
        priceBs:645000}).then(hola => console.log(hola);
```